# RethinkDB + Horizon with Windows Authentication (Active Directory SSO)

Tags: active-directory, windows-authentication, rethinkdb, horizon

Is there a way to secure a [Horizon](http://horizon.io/) app (with [RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com/)) using Windows Authentication (SSO) with an internal Active Directory?
I would like to be able to restrict access based on the Windows/Domain user and also load the AD profile info somehow in my single page web app?

The catch: Everything needs to run on premise. So no cloud or any external providers. Just the local company Active Directory and Windows environment.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to do that right now, but you could embed Horizon into a node app and handle the authentication yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hmm ok, yeah I though about that as well, but that would mean that I have to essentially write my own backend, right?

Or is there a way to forward / expose the fetch().subscribe() to my client without writing a method for each collection?